# what's the code meaning?

Tags: php

I am a newbie of php. what's the following code meaning?

```
  <?php if ($i>3): continue; endif; ?>
```

why the above isn't write like this.

```
<?php if ($i>3) { continue;} ?>
```

Comment: Both are legit; if-endif construct may be slightly more readable if its body is loooooong enough.

Comment: Well, apparently you know the meaning. Why it's written in longhand and not using curly braces nobody can tell you. They're identical.

Answer (score 4):

The colon nomenclature is normally used in templates, where UI and graphic guys do work. Guess it makes it easier to read. and work with.

Consider:

```
<?php if ($foo == 'bar'): ?>
<div>
    ...
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

vs

```
<?php if ($foo == 'bar') { ?>
<div>
    ....
</div>
<?php } // after a few nested sets, these get hard to follow when there is a lot of html scattered throughout ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Either way works.

In the case you posted, they're essentially equivalent. Were the PHP to look like this:

```
<?php if ($i > 3): ?>
    [ some HTML here ... ]
<?php endif; ?>
```

... then the "block" style quotes are disfavored by some. The key advantage of "endif" and "endfor" is that they make it clear *which* type of statement you are ending, where a "}" could close any open-brace.

The difference is stylistic, but it's a useful symmetry with other templating engines.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the "alternative syntax" for control structures (like `if`, `for`, etc.) in PHP.  Here is the documentation on it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php .

It's particularly useful for when you are embedding PHP tags in HTML pages (at least for readability.)

Answer (score 1):

PHP has some documentation on this:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

It is basically another way of doing control structures. Instead of a { and a } (like C) to delimit your if statement, you use a : and a endif (more akin to Pascal).

All in all, it's just personal preference.